# I have a function with chained promises after which I want to return an integer value but I get undefined before function is resolved

Tags: node.js

I have created a function that downloads a PDF then reads it and finds the number of pages with chained promises. I want to return the value of the pages when this function is called.

However when I write `var b = await ExtractLength(url, destinationFolder,filename);` in my main function then `console.log(b)` I am getting a value of `undefined`. If I understand correctly the variable `b` is assigned the value before the promises are resolved. I have tried some alternatives but I don't understand what the problem is. Why is this happening and how I can fix it?

Here is my function:

```
async function ExtractLength(url, destination, flnm){
    var options ={
        directory: destination,
        filename: flnm
    }
    await download(url, options, async function(error){
        if (error){
            console.log("Download error: ", error);
            return null;
        }
        await fs.readFile(destination+flnm, async function(err,dataBuffer){
            if (err){
                console.log("Read file error: ", err);
                return null;
            }
            await pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data){
                console.log("Number of pages: ", data.numpages);
                return data.numpages;
            })
            .catch(function(erro){
                console.log("Pdf error: ",erro);
                return null;
            });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: You never assign or return the result of `await`ing the promises, `ExtractLength` is a promise of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines

```
await download(url, options, async function(error){

    await fs.readFile(destination+flnm, async function(err,dataBuffer){

        await pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data){
```

to have returns like so

```
return await download(url, options, async function(error){

    return await fs.readFile(destination+flnm, async function(err,dataBuffer)

        return await pdf(dataBuffer).then(function(data){
```

You must return a value for your Extract, your readfile function, and your pdf function calls.

To further explain: in each of those chained calls, you're passing anonymous functions for them call, and even though each anonymous function returns a value, you never assign the final value to anything within the Extract call that kicks it all off.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I already tried this and it is still not working, do you have any idea why? By the way I forgot to mention download is from the npm package "download-pdf" and pdf is from the npm package "pdf-parse". I don't know If that factors into the problem.

Comment: Is download-pdf actually downloading the PDF to the destination? And if so, does your readFile successfully return a databuffer? And if so, does the your pdf(dataBuffer) call successfully call the underlying callback?

Comment: Yes all of them are working perfectly, the file is downloaded and the buffer works because I get the console message with the correct number of pages from inside the function. It is only when I call the function from my main function that I get undefined. I don't understand why but the console log of the main function appears before the one in the function.

Comment: You're missing another return inside ExtractLength function. I've edited my answer to include this.

Comment: I am still getting b= undefined. I don't know what else to do, is there a way to force the console.log() command in the main function to wait until the call to my function ExtractLength() is completed?

Comment: Oh gosh.. there's a third return statement you need.. return pdf. I've edited the answer

Comment: Yes I imagined there should be another one for pdf, it is still not working.

Comment: At this point, I'd suggest you assign each return statement to a variable, debug your code at each point, and inspect each variable to see where it is breaking down. If you're unable to debug your code, put a log statement after each await and see what is being returned -- but I highly suggest learning how to debug your node in something like Visual Code as that will save you a lot of time tracking down issues like this as you'll be able to see variables in real-time as the code is being executed https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_attaching-to-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Your code here is a bit of an antipattern. You usually shouldn't be using both a callback and a `Promise`. JS `async` and `await` are used to get the result of a promise into a variable. For example `const x = await Promise.resolve(5); // x = 5`

I believe AWS does support both callbacks and promises so just choose one or the other. It looks like you have a good handle on callbacks so the simplest way would probably be removing any `async` and `await` keywords. Promises are definitely worth learning!

It would be easier to give a definite solution using the two approaches if you showed us where the `download` function comes from.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I removed all the async, await keywords and I am still getting b= undefined as a result. Also,  download is from the npm package "download-pdf" and pdf is from the npm package "pdf-parse". Does this explain why it still gives me a wrong answer?